# Как называется эффект на сайте и как реализовать

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Доброго всем времени суток. Мне понравился один эффект на сайте (https://ru.wix.com/), а именно при прокручивании вниз экран поднимается вверх, а под ним проявляется другой, типа как колода карт. Как этот эффект называется и как реализуется? Мне не надо алгоритм, мне бы желательно узнать направление: с помощью какой технологии решается, какие методы будут интересны. Буду благодарен за совет. И прошу давать ответ не как комментарий, а полноценно(что бы я мог поставить галочку за наиболее подходящий вариант, да и вам в бонус очки:))  )

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bA6RCe-d0Lc

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По просьбе автора, ответ в ответ, а не в комментарий - выше указано верно, учить и изучать вам необходимо именно javascript, так как этот эффект реализован не так то уж и сложно, но все завязано именно на js. Если вы открыв указанный вами сайт откроете еще и инструменты разработчика в браузере, поиграв со скроллом вы поймете как это реализовано (область с контентом сайта изначально абсолютно прозрачна и при скролле становиться видимой, ну и так далее). Так что учите всю связку для начала html5, css и javascript! И сможете сами без труда реализовывать подобное. Удачи в изучении.

Comment: Спасибо, я это и делал. Но не понял от чего оттолкнуться. Мне и требовалось направление, хотя уже тоже дошел до связки  JS и CSS